# Is it possible to add Exp Date to a CSR

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

Is it possible to add the expiration date of the certificate in a CSR request?

```
public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateCSR(KeyPair keyPair) throws IOException, OperatorCreationException {
    String principal = "CN=AWS IoT Certificate" + ", O=Amazon";
    AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory.createKey(keyPair.getPrivate()
            .getEncoded());
    AlgorithmIdentifier signatureAlgorithm = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder()
            .find("SHA1WITHRSA");
    AlgorithmIdentifier digestAlgorithm = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder()
            .find("SHA-1");
    ContentSigner signer = new BcRSAContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm, digestAlgorithm)
            .build(privateKey);

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
            new X500Name(principal), keyPair.getPublic());
    ExtensionsGenerator extensionsGenerator = new ExtensionsGenerator();
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(
            true));
    csrBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, extensionsGenerator.generate());
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = csrBuilder.build(signer);

    return csr;
}
```

Comment: No. The validity (start date and expiration date) are decided by the certifying authority, so there is no defined attribute to specify them in a CSR.

Comment: Thanks, if you add it as an answer I'll accept it.